# asp.net core video streaming, multiple requests from the same client

Tags: asp.net-core, video-streaming

I am streaming a video from an asp.net core app.

The code is handling range requests, which allows the user to seek anywhere in the video.

The issue is that the HTML5 video player will start a new request when you seek somewhere in the video and the previous request is still being fulfilled.

So, if you skip around the video 5-6 times, you will have 5-6 outgoing streams.

Has anyone any experience with how to handle this?

Comment: How big are the ranges?

Comment: I'm doing tests with a 1.6gb movie; I started with a 64kb buffer and a seek would leave a stream open for 15-20 seconds; I switched to a 4kb buffer and streams die much faster.

Comment: Now the HTML5 player always seems to request from wherever the user seeks to until the end of the movie, so the ranges are very large

Comment: One test now revealed that when you open a movie with VLC, it will request the beginning of the movie and the end of the movie, then starts playing. These stream end because they are small. But during the main playback, if I close VLC, the streaming continues. Does it make sense that I control the size of the range I sent and have the player keep requesting instead of fulfilling a large range request?

Comment: It appears that the client closing the connection is not actually notifying the server to stop sending the response. If your code is async, make sure you're employing cancellation tokens.

Comment: I need to look into that, I never used cancellation tokens

Comment: Check RequestAborted

Comment: You have the scenario where a user is watching a video and kills the player, so there is no notification of any kind going out; also, Im not controlling the player itself so I need to find a way to protect the server from random aborts

Comment: If I get a request with a range of currentposition:endofmovie, am I allowed to return currentposition:+5seconds? This would force the player in requesting more chunks regularly but I don't know if this is allowed in the standard

Comment: I just checked it and VLC stops playing the video if I provide a shorter range, so it's not asking for more